# I currently have a pandas series and I want to split to only get the integer in every single row

Tags: python, dataframe

```
    0
4   ['cancelled:', '5']
37  ['cancelled:', '7']
70  ['cancelled:', '1']
103 ['cancelled:', '4']
136 ['cancelled:', '5']
169 ['cancelled:', '1']
202 ['cancelled:', '153']
235 ['cancelled:', '3']
268 ['cancelled:', '7']
301 ['cancelled:', '1']
334 ['cancelled:', '2']
```

This is my output and I want to split each row so that I can get the integer value after the comma. Some of the integers have different values so I cant use

```
.str.split(']').str[0].str[-2:-1]
```

Is there anyway to use the method above to only get the integer? Meaning splitting to from the right of the comma and then using astype(int) to change every value into an integer since I have strings?

Comment: are these strings or lists?

Answer (score 0):

If those are lists you can get the integer with

```py
your_series.str.get(-1).astype(int)
```

If they are strings, you could cast them into lists first and then proceed as above:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

your_series.apply(literal_eval).str.get(-1).astype(int)
```